# Transaction isolation level/design for write-only ledger

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, transaction, isolation-level

This is a simplified example of a problem I've been working on. Say I have the following database schema:

```
Table: Deposits
+--------+------------+--------+---------+
|   ID   |    Date    | Amount | User ID |
+--------+------------+--------+---------+
| c1f... | 1589993488 |   40.0 | 6c7...  |
| bfe... | 1589994420 |   30.0 | 744...  |
+--------+------------+--------+---------+
```

```
Table: Withdrawals
+--------+------------+--------+---------+
|   ID   |    Date    | Amount | User ID |
+--------+------------+--------+---------+
| ad4... | 1589995414 |   20.0 | 6c7...  |
| e9b... | 1589996417 |   20.0 | 6c7...  |
+--------+------------+--------+---------+
```

And I'm writing a function that **performs a withdrawal** for a User. It:

1. Sums the deposits (`SELECT amount FROM deposits WHERE user_id = ...`)
2. Sums the withdrawals (`SELECT amount FROM withdrawals WHERE user_id = ...`)
3. If the difference is greater than the requested amount, `INSERT`s a new Withdrawal

We're using MySQL 8 and the default isolation level of `REPEATABLE READ`.

This function may be running as a lambda, so memory locks are not an option, and we don't have distributed locking (ie. a Redid-based lock) available.

**A Caveat**

There are existing admin operations run at the `REPEATABLE READ` level to create/delete these entities on-demand, by ID.

**My Questions:**

1. Am I correct in understanding that I need to use `SERIALIZABLE` as the isolation level for this transaction?
2. Will the `SERIALIZABLE` range lock prevent the `REPEATABLE READ` transaction from inserting new rows into the Withdrawals, or removing rows from the Deposits?

Comment: You say "sum", yet there is not `SUM()` in the `SELECT`.  Please show us the real code, not hand-waving.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have `FOR UPDATE` on the end of the `SELECTs`.  Else another connection could sneak in and change the results of the `SELECTs`.

Also, steps 1,2,3 need to be inside a single `TRANSACTION`.

Once you do all that, you can probably leave the isolation level at the default.